# How can I execute script after entire webpage has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simply script. For example:

```
var rowCount = $('tr').length;
document.write(rowCount);
```

I want to load this after entire webpage has loaded. How can I do?

Comment: `$( window ).load(function() { ... }) `?. See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score -1):

Use following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
     var rowCount = $('tr').length;
      document.write(rowCount);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready` doesn't wait for images to load. Also, how is this different from nikhil's answer?

Comment: Both are answered same time dude.. :| and where is OP mentioned about image :O?

Comment: No, dude, they're a minute apart.